# C++ Qt QAudioInput + QIODevice

Tags: c++, qt, microphone

My purpose is to capture sound from microphone and playback in real time. The problem is that when i press Start button, there are a few messages in Application Output like QAudioInput: IOError, can't write to QIODevice.
I was looking at the example "qaudioinput" .
In the way of commenting each line, i found out that the problem is in line
audioInput->start(devInput);
when the next line 
audioOutput->start(devOutput); 
works normally. 
And one more, can anybody explain about push and pull modes in qaudioinput example? There is no information in the internet about it.

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QtMultimedia/QAudioFormat>
#include <QtMultimedia/QAudioInput>
#include <QtMultimedia/QAudioOutput>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QIODevice>

class audioIn : public QIODevice
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    audioIn(const QAudioFormat &format, QObject *parent);
    ~audioIn();
    qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 len);
    qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen);
    void start();
    void stop();
private:
    const QAudioFormat m_format;
};
class audioOut : public QIODevice
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    audioOut(const QAudioFormat &format, QObject *parent);
    ~audioOut();
    qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 len);
    qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen);
    void start();
    void stop();
private:
    const QAudioFormat m_format;
};

class mainwindow:public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    mainwindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~mainwindow();
private:
    QHBoxLayout* layout;
    QPushButton* start;
    QByteArray buffer;
    QAudioFormat m_format;
    QAudioInput* audioInput;
    QAudioOutput* audioOutput;
    audioIn* devInput;
    audioOut* devOutput;
    QIODevice* m_input;
    QIODevice* m_output;

public slots:
    void startrec();
    void readMore();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

audioIn::audioIn(const QAudioFormat &format, QObject *parent):QIODevice(parent), m_format(format)
{

}
audioIn::~audioIn()
{
}
void audioIn::start()
{
    open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
}
void audioIn::stop()
{
    close();
}
qint64 audioIn::readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen)
{
    Q_UNUSED(data);
    Q_UNUSED(maxlen);
    return 0;
}
qint64 audioIn::writeData(const char *data, qint64 len)
{
    Q_UNUSED(data);
    Q_UNUSED(len);
    return 0;
}

audioOut::audioOut(const QAudioFormat &format, QObject *parent):QIODevice(parent), m_format(format)
{

}
audioOut::~audioOut()
{
}
void audioOut::start()
{
    open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
}
void audioOut::stop()
{
    close();
}
qint64 audioOut::readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen)
{
    Q_UNUSED(data);
    Q_UNUSED(maxlen);
    return 0;
}
qint64 audioOut::writeData(const char *data, qint64 len)
{
    Q_UNUSED(data);
    Q_UNUSED(len);
    return 0;
}

mainwindow::mainwindow(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent)
{
    layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    start = new QPushButton("Start");
    layout->addWidget(start);
    setLayout(layout);
    connect(start, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(startrec()));
}
mainwindow::~mainwindow()
{

}

void mainwindow::startrec()
{
    m_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    m_format.setChannelCount(2);
    m_format.setSampleRate(44100);
    m_format.setSampleSize(16);
    m_format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    m_format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    QAudioDeviceInfo infoIn(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice());
    if(!infoIn.isFormatSupported(m_format))
        m_format = infoIn.nearestFormat(m_format);
    devInput = new audioIn(m_format, this);
    audioInput = new QAudioInput(infoIn, m_format, this);

    QAudioDeviceInfo infoOut(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
    if(!infoOut.isFormatSupported(m_format))
        m_format = infoOut.nearestFormat(m_format);
    devOutput = new audioOut(m_format, this);
    audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(infoOut,m_format, this);

    devInput->start();
    devOutput->start();
    m_input = audioInput->start();
    m_output = audioOutput->start();

    connect(m_input, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(readMore()));
}

void mainwindow::readMore()
{
    qint64 len = audioInput->bytesReady();
    if(len > 7056)
        len = 7056;
    qint64 l = m_input->read(buffer.data(), len);
    if(l > 0)
        m_output->write(buffer.constData(), l);
}
```

Comment: instead
devInput->start();
devOutput->start();
m_input = audioInput->start();
m_output = audioOutput->start();

there is

devInput->start();
    devOutput->start();
    audioInput->start(devInput);
    audioOutput->start(devOutput);
and in readMore instead m_input and m_output there is devInput and devOutput

Comment: The error is self explnatory _IOError, can't write to QIODevice_ .. your device needs to be open in `write` mode

Comment: Qt and "real time" don't stack up. Especially on windows.

Comment: audioIn is already opened in write mode

Comment: void audioIn::start()
{
    open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
}

Comment: Yes, but what is that going to open .. apparently `parent` .. and I don't see you are getting this to be your `buffer` ?

Comment: Where you want to store the audio stream before playing it ?

Comment: in your code `qint64 l = m_input->read(buffer.data(), len);` your are reading the `buffer` without opening it and in next line you are writing to `buffer` also .. may be I am missing something .. but that buffer is not `open()`

Comment: buffer is QByteArray and as i know, i don't need to open it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
void audioIn::start()
{
    open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
}
```

If you want to *read* from a device, better open it in ReadOnly or ReadWrite mode....

(clearly your audioIn class needs to read data, not write).

Comment: your are right, but the thing is this part of the code is taken from Qt examples.  The OP is trying to extend the functionality .. but to _To me_ it is not clear

Comment: Okay, tomorrow i'll try to review my code and fix it. Thank you

Comment: If i set audioIn::start() to ReadOnly, it says:
QIODevice::write (audioIn): ReadOnly device
QAudioInput: IOError

Comment: Wait a minute... what does audioIn actually do? You create it, it's derived from QIODevice but you never specify *what* it is supposed to open. I think you need to rethink your code; why do you have devInput and audioInput??